# an issue with off state of the analog switch?

Tags: switches

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTmbo7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using  4066 analog switch to feed 2.2v dc when it is on its giving 2.2v but when it's in off state still it is giving 1.12v can we reduce it to zero volts in off state. a voltage at v2. sw1 sw2 has the same control signal. here c1 and c2 are also variable and connected in half bridge differential configuration.
in control signal, I have applied a pulse of a 0-5v pulse having a frequency of 10 kHz

Comment: Can you draw a diagram? I don't quite understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Schematic and punctuation or vote to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You've had several hours to answer queries raised in comments. Don't post a question and depart thinking you'll come back tomorrow to a bunch of great answers. Stick around for an hour and add the detail to the question that is requested. I've voted to close this question as unclear.

Comment: What supply voltages are used? And what control voltages? Show your schematic, logic levels, and supply voltages. For some combinations of control and supply, the internal FETs will **not** be off.

Comment: Double-click the components in your schematic to set the values. (1) You can't power a TL081 from a 1 V supply. (2) V1 needs a ground reference somewhere or no current can flow into the op-amp.

Comment: I can't deduce what your 2.2 V source is, nor where you're measuring the 1.12 V.  There are also significant errors and ambiguities in both your schematic and your text.

Answer (score 1):

In the off state, a CMOS switch has a leakage current to all terminals.

If the load resistance is high, for instance a DMM with an input impedance of 10Mohm, then even a small leakage current could generate a significant voltage.

Assuming your 1.12v is measured into 10Mohms, that corresponds to a current of 112nA.

The data sheet shows a maximum leakage current of +/- 100nA over the full temperature range, and typically 10pA at 25C, so unless you have a 'bad' 4066, it's unlikely to be leakage, possible, but unlikely.

112nA is still a small current, so it's possible you might be getting surface leakage through moisture or fingerprints on the board.

How are you putting  the 4066 into the 'off' state? If by disconnecting the control signal, then that could leave the part still conducting somewhat. These need to be turned off by taking the logic input valid low.

Comment: thanks, sir.... as a control signal I have applied a pulse 0-5 v  signal generated through 555 timer in astable mode

Answer (score 0):

A switch is not a voltage source. It is not clear what you mean. If the switch is off, it is behaving as a high resistance, and it forms a divider with the load (assuming you are driving with a low impedance voltage source). I assume that you had an open as load, i.e. infinite resistance. In this case the switch parasitics determine the voltage. Even if the switch has infinite resistance in off state, there is a capacitive feed-through path from the control voltage, and it might have the similar capacitance as the output. In this case the falling edge of the control voltage will sip some charges from the output capacitance as well. You can think of it that these to capacitors are in series.  (though there might be another caps as well.)

Add some capacitance or resistance to the output of the switch and it should work fine.

PS: I am not familiar with 4066. I've written my comment on general switches.